Unable to hold state and rebuild the widget
`I am making a flutter application using Riverpod. I am using country_state_city_pro.dart in my registration page.
TextEditingController countryCont = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController stateCont = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController cityCont = TextEditingController();

// Define CountryStateCityPicker widget
CountryStateCityPicker(
  country: countryCont,
  state: stateCont,
  city: cityCont,
  dialogColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
  textFieldDecoration: InputDecoration(
    fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
    filled: true,
    suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward_rounded),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
  ),
  onChanged: (country, state, city) {
    // Accept the value entered by the user and debug print it
    print('Country: $country, State: $state, City: $city');

    // Set the state of the UI and rebuild the widget
    setState(() {
      countryCont.text = country ?? '';
      stateCont.text = state ?? '';
      cityCont.text = city ?? '';
    });
  },
),

Problem:
I want to store the state of the widget based on the user's choice and rebuild the widget to reflect user's choice
I have tried to use onChanged() function but it gives an error:
Undefined name 'onChanged'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.`your text``

I cant find onChanged on your snippet, can you provide a full minimal snippet that will reproduce the same error

@Md.YeasinSheikh Sure here's the updated the code

The CountryStateCityPicker widget doesn't provide an onChanged parameter, but you can add your own listener to the controllers:
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  TextEditingController countryCont = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController stateCont = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController cityCont = TextEditingController();

  // Define your own `onChanged` method
  void onChanged() {
    final country = countryCont.text;
    final state = stateCont.text;
    final city = cityCont.text;

    // Do something with the values
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Register `onChanged` as the listener for every controller
    countryCont.addListener(onChanged);
    stateCont.addListener(onChanged);
    cityCont.addListener(onChanged);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Don't forget to remove the listeners and dispose of the controllers
    countryCont
      ..removeListener(onChanged)
      ..dispose();
    stateCont
      ..removeListener(onChanged)
      ..dispose();
    cityCont
      ..removeListener(onChanged)
      ..dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CountryStateCityPicker(
      // ...
    );
  }
}

With this approach, you also have the flexibility to register every controller its own listener, such as onCountryChanged etc.
